# Turn off / delete "Smooth Sliding Screen" function in UI 3.0 ( realme smartphone )

Tags: adb

How can be turned off / uninstalled "Smooth Sliding Screen" function from realme smartphone? It is an adb command to achieve that?

In UI 3.0 this function is forced enabled globally and not an option like in UI 2.0.